# Пропадают стили у страницы

Tags: php

Есть роут:

```
if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
    {
        $controller_name = $routes[1];
    }

    // получаем имя экшена
    if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
    {

        $action_name = $routes[2];

    }
    if ( isset($routes[3]) ) {
        $params = array_slice($routes, 2);
    }
```

В `$params` у меня хранится все что нужно, и передается в контроллер как надо, НО если я пытаюсь ввести строку типа:

> http://example.ru/category/index/2/3

То у меня тут же пропадают все css стили у страницы, чем это может быть вызвано?
P.S. по адресу:

> http://example.ru/category/index/2

Все работает нормально.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста как подключаете CSS-стили?

Comment: @cheops стили подключаю в файле-шаблоне: `<link href="../../resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../resource/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../resource/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../resource/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../resource/css/plugins/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../resource/css/plugins/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так часто бывает, если ссылка на каскадную таблицу стилей относительная

```
<link href="../../resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Для каждого уровня вложения category/index/2 или category/index/2/3 вам придется высчитывать свой собственный относительный путь. Лучше воспользоваться абсолютным путем от корня сайта

```
<link href="/resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

В этом случае стили будут корректно подключены к страницам с любой степенью вложенности.

Comment: Странно почему тогда по адресу "http://example.ru/category/index/2" все работало и с относительными ссылками.. спасибо!

Comment: А для этого пути ваш относительный путь как раз корректный. Если вы добавите еще один ../, но на этой странице стили перестанут работать, зато на category/index/2/3 - начнут. Этим относительные ссылки и не удобны - вам их нужно либо каждый раз вычислять, либо использовать лишь один уровень вложения на сайте.